# how does any([a == b for a, b in zip(string, string[1:])]) work

Tags: python

I am learning python by doing online challanges.

The goal of this challenge is to analyze a string to check if it contains two of the same letter in a row. For example, the string `"hello"` has `l` twice in a row, while the string `"nono"` does not have two identical letters in a row.

Define a function named `double_letters` that takes a single parameter. The parameter is a string. Your function must return `True` if there are two identical letters in a row in the string, and `False` otherwise.

my solution:

```
def double_letters(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == word[i-1]:
            return True
    return False
```

apparently though,

```
def double_letters(string):
    return any([a == b for a, b in zip(string, string[1:])])
```

is a better solution,
what is the logic behind it (I understand what a zip function does)

Comment: What is it that you don't understand, specifically? `any`? The syntax? Something else?

Comment: Your solution is actually better in at least one sense: it doesn’t use any unnecessary memory, and has better best-case time. `return any(a == b for a, b in pairwise(string))` (given [`import pairwise from itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)) would fix that, though.

Comment: @Ry- I think (it kinda says in the docs _New in version 3.10._) that `pairwise` was added only in 3.10, so for older versions using `islice` seems to be better (better than `[1:]`) (or using the _rough implementation_ that is shown under the `pairwise` function in the docs)

Comment: Oh, but your solution also has a bug. Try `"non"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your function has a bug - it believes that the first and last letters are next to each other, and `double_letters('non')` is `True`.
(Finding the bug left as an exercise. It's an "off by one" problem.)

`zip(string, string[1:])` creates pairs of consecutive letters from the strings.

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> list(zip(s, s[1:]))
[('h', 'e'), ('e', 'l'), ('l', 'l'), ('l', 'o')]
```

`[a == b for a, b in zip(string, string[1:])]` is a list comprehension that deconstructs each pair (`for a, b in zip(string, string[1:])`) and produces `True` elements when they are equal, `False` elements when they are not.

```
>>> [a == b for a, b in zip(s, s[1:])]
[False, False, True, False]
```

`any` is a function that takes an iterable and returns `True` if at least one of the elements is `True`.

```
>>> any([False, False])
False
>>> any([False, True, False])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what that code is doing is comparing the current character with the one next to it, simply by getting the shifted over version and comparing them.

It is a fancy and compact way of writing:

`return any(a == b where b is the character after a)`

What the zip is doing is something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# a  b
 [1, 2]
 [2, 3]
 [3, 4]
 [4, 5]
 [5, None]
```

... and where they are equal, it will return true.